# How can I randomize object instance's rotation?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

i made one rotating cube.

and i set the cube to object instance node.

and i turned off "remove animation data" in item tab.

so the instanced cube rotates same as original cube.

what i want to do is let them rotates randomly.

i wish for if someone gives me advices.
thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward once you get ahold of the fcurves, which is the data used by Blender to animate properties.

This node tree works only for animated rotation, but you can easily expand it to take into account scale or location animations, by accessing the other fcurves.

First, add a group which we will use to extract each fcurve data at a given frame, and add an offset to it, with an integer as a parameter to randomize it for each individual cube.

[image]

**Important :**

- Set the "Random Number" node to min =  - your max frame number (in my case -100) and max = min frame number (here, 0)
- Set the "Repeat time" node to loop above your max frame number.
- Set the "Evaluate Fcruve" node to Absolute

Then, simply loop over each object and gather the result of each fcurve, then assign it to your object's rotation :

[image]

Note that the rotations are in Radians.

My main tree looks like this :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: thank you   i read it again, and iwill reply after i try your advice

Comment: Yes, I didn't read your question carefully at first, you should be good to go with this solution. If your animation is simple, you can consider doing it all in Animation Nodes which offers great solutions for, well, animation !

Comment: thank you very much.I could do.